# "No such module: AVFAudio" xcode build fails on older machine but works fine on newer

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am attempting to build a project on my local machine, an old but still functional macbook pro from 2013.  The project builds and runs just fine on newer computers, but fails to build or archive on the 2013 machine.  It gives me the following error:

..../App.swift:10:9: No such module 'AVFAudio'

This is on a clean pull of the repository, no local changes have been made.  I have the latest version of xcode that is compatible with my computer.

Answer (score 1):

`AVFAudio` is only available on iOS 14.5+ (source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio).

That means that if you're using an older version of Xcode that doesn't support 14.5+ (which sounds likely, given the fact that it's an older machine), then you won't have access to that framework.

If possible, download Xcode 12.5+ and try to build and run again.

Comment: Did this answer your question?